# JPA 2 implementations benchmark comparison

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, benchmarking

Is there any benchmark comparison of JPA 2 implementations?
I need comparison from several aspects: simple entity operations, collections, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one might help:

[JPA Performance Benchmark](http://www.jpab.org/All/All/All.html)

It includes several tests, operations and batch modes.